# Show the existence of a partition of $[a,b]$ satisfying $|f(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i})|<\epsilon$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$, and let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous and monotone. Show that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite partition  $a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b$ of $[a,b]$ satisfying $|f(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i})|<\epsilon$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

My attempt:

Suppose $f$ is monotone increasing and $f(a)<f(b)$ (If $f$ is constant then the result is trivial). Choose $n$ large enough so that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and consider the equally spaced partition $f(a)=y_0<y_1<\dots<y_n=f(b)$  of $[f(a),f(b)]$ defined by  $y_i=f(a)+\frac{i}{n}(f(b)-f(a))$ for $i=0,\dots,n$.

Now, by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20the%20intermediate,some%20point%20within%20the%20interval.&text=The%20image%20of%20a%20continuous,interval%20is%20itself%20an%20interval.), there exists for each $i=1,\dots,n$ a real number $x_i\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_i)\in(y_{i-1},y_i)$. Moreover by monotonicity of $f$ we must have $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$. Define $x_0:=a$ and $x_{n+1}:=b$. Then the partition $\{x_0,x_1\dots,x_{n+1}\}$ of $[a,b]$ does what is wanted.

The case where $f$ is monotone decreasing can be deduced by applying the previous case to $-f$.

Is this correct? Also, it seems that continuity is not needed if $f$ is strictly monotone, for then we can take the partition $x_i=f^{-1}(y_i)$ for $i=0,\dots,n$.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is **uniformly** continuous...

Comment: If $f$ is strictly monotone but discontinuous then $f^{-1}(y_j)$ can be empty

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see. From the definition uniform continuity we see that any partition of $[a,b]$ with mesh small enough will do. Is my proof ok still ? And strictly monotone is not sufficient for the result?

Comment: I can't tell whether your proof is ok since you haven't shown a proof, other than the one above assuming monotonicity. No, strict montonicity is not enough: say $[a,b]=[0,2]$, $$f(t)=\begin{cases}t,&(0,\le t\le 1),\\t+1,&(1<t\le 2\end{cases}.$$